# Fabric.js - problems with pattern fill on fabric.Text using patternTransform

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I found something really weird. I'm struggle with transforming patterns on `fabric.Text` objects. I create pattern for object like this:

```js
fabric.util.loadImage(path, (img) => {
    this.object.fill = new fabric.Pattern({source:img}, () => {
        this.object.dirty = true
        canvas.renderAll()
    })
})
```

It looks fine. I can change `fill.offsetX` and `fill.offsetY` and it works like excepted:

[image: pattern fill]

For transforming patterns I use `fill.patternTransform` when I can set transformation matrix for scale etc. When I change scale down my pattern using matrix:

```js
this.object.fill.transformMatrix = [.77, 0, 0, .77, 0, 0]
```

things get interesting:

[image: wrong pattern fill]

This does not happen when I applying same pattern for other objects (paths, rects, circles etc.). I can scale pattern correctly:

[image: correct pattern fill on circle]

I don't want to use DynamicPattern method presented in fabric.js examples because I need `fill.patternTransform` transformation matrix for future use.

Any ideas?

Working jsfiddle example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhwmj1pa/)

I'm using **fabric@2.6.0**.